# Where is the triggers panel in Expression Blend 4?

Tags: expression-blend, blend

I cannot find the triggers panel in Expression Blend 4.

Tutorials everywhere show it in screenshots of the IDE:

[image: img]

But I cannot select that view:

[image: img2]

How can I open that view? I need to add event and property triggers with Blend.

So annoying!

Comment: Can you confirm that you're running Expression Blend 4? It looks like you're running 5.

Answer (score 1):

In Expression Blend 5, Triggers were replaced with Behaviors and Actions.

First select an element then open the Assets pane and double-click on the behavior you want to add to the element, or open the Properties pane and scroll to the Actions and Behaviors area to add them.